# Reported Speech Tense Choice

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-perfect, past-perfect

Which of the followings sentences would be the best choice?

> The victim explained how he became addicted five years ago...
>
> 1. His addiction ***is*** so bad that he ***is*** unable to keep a steady relationship.
> 2. His addiction ***has been*** so bad that he ***has been*** unable to keep a steady relationship.
> 3. His addiction ***has been*** so bad that he ***is*** unable to keep a steady relationship.
> 4. His addiction ***had been*** so bad that he ***was*** unable to keep a steady relationship.
> 5. His addiction ***had been*** so bad that he ***had been*** unable to keep a steady relationship.

He hasn't treated his addiction yet.

Comment: They're all grammatical, but each has different time references - and they're not examples of reported speech. Could you tell us why you are asking?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was an example of reported speech although the reporting verb was in another sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examples 1 and 2 sound fine to me, although for clarity's sake I would change their wording a little bit.  Number 1 would then become,  "His addiction *today* is so bad that he is unable to keep a steady relationship."  Number 2 would then become,  "*Since then*, his addiction has become so bad that he has been unable to keep a steady relationship."

Example 3 is a little confusing by its combining of the past and present.  The sentence starts out by referring to a time in the past (which could have been a few weeks or a few years ago).  The reader then expects the writer to provide an example from the past, indicating how bad the addiction has been (and not as it is now).  Hence, a better wording would be, "His addiction has been so bad that he *has been unable* to keep a steady relationship."  Another possibility is, "His addiction has been so bad that *[at one point] he was unable* to keep a steady relationship."  (While still addicted today, he may nevertheless be able to keep a steady relationship.)

Examples 4 and 5 can be eliminated because the victim, I assume, is still addicted.  The "had been" from each example makes it sound as if the addiction is a thing of the past, which it is not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was exactly what I was asking for.